# Ethereum performance using whiteblock

Tags: testing, benchmark

I have recently heard about [whiteblock testing platform](https://whiteblock.io), however, there is no details on how to build your own test. Do you have any idea about how to use it and how powerful the platform is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm CTO of Whiteblock. We just opened the beta program for our SaaS testing platform. Needless to say, things have been pretty busy for us and we haven't even had time to update our website appropriately to share these details with the public.

Either way, if you need to set up a test net or have other specific testing needs, I'd love to give you a free trial of the platform if you're interested. In the meantime, please check out our [website](https://www.whiteblock.io) for more high-level details. Send me a message in the [Telegram group](https://t.me/whiteblockio) so we can chat and get the ball rolling.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes I would like to try your platform to perform my own test.